# Create React App with TypeScript and NPM Link: Enums causing Module parse failed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babel-loader, npm-link

I have a basic `create-react-app` TypeScript project (`client`). Just directory up, I have a `server` and a `shared` folder. Inside the `shared` folder I have a number of `interface`s and `enum`s that I share between the `server` and the `client`.

I wish to link this `shared` folder to both the `client` and `server` packages.

First, I went to `shared` and ran `$ yarn link` and then ran `$ yarn link shared` from both the `client` and the `server` folders.

The server is as happy as can be, and for the most part the client is too. However, as soon as I use one of the `enum`s from the `shared` directory in the `client`, I get an error:

```
../shared/src/models/Roles.ts 4:0
Module parse failed: The keyword 'enum' is reserved (4:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| $RefreshSetup$(module.id);
| 
> enum Roles {
|     RW_ORG = "rw_org", // can modifiy organization and it's users, nothing else
```

I'm importing it like so:
`import {Roles} from "shared";`
but have tried numerous other ways as well.

I'm exporting it from the `shared` `index.ts` like so

```
import Roles from "./models/Roles";

export type { 
    // all of my interfaces
};
export { Roles }
```

All of my `interface`s are usable, so I don't understand. What the hell is going on here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, it turns out that these errors are all cause by create-react-app's default `webpack.config.js`. If you navigate to `code node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js` you fill find a line `include: paths.appSrc` which basically limits Babel to the `src/` folder of the react app itself.

That means, if you've `yarn link`ed a folder outside of it, Babel will not transpile it to normal JS, and thus React cannot use it.

There are two hacky solutions, but I would like a better one.

1. Manually (or via a build script) delete the `include: paths.appSrc` line from `react-scripts` every time you install a node module
2. Make a script that copies the external directory into your React `src` directory every time the external directory is modified.

I really wish there were an official way around this...

Comment: I got into a similar problem, and solved it by putting the ORIGINAL (shared) folder inside the react app source and the linked folder inside the server which doesn't care about this as the react-script does :)

Comment: @YochailLehman Yes, that's another possible solution. Honestly though, the best thing to do is just to do one of these options until you're ready to make your shared directory into an actual module. At that point you should build the shared module when you make changes and install it as a local package (or a hosted package somewhere) rather than rely on linking or anything.

Comment: I automated it with @craco/craco: https://gist.github.com/PhilippMolitor/00f427d12a9c5bca84309058d88846b7

Comment: You can also use `include: [paths.appSrc, /\.(ts|tsx)$/]`

Answer (score 8):

Based on @foxtrotuniform6969's answer, i created a `@cracro/craco` configuration that gets rid of the misbehaving setting by itself.

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig) => ({
      ...webpackConfig,
      module: {
        ...webpackConfig.module,
        rules: webpackConfig.module.rules.map((rule) => {
          if (!rule.oneOf) return rule;
          return {
            ...rule,
            oneOf: rule.oneOf.map((ruleObject) => {
              if (
                !new RegExp(ruleObject.test).test('.ts') ||
                !ruleObject.include
              )
                return ruleObject;
              return { ...ruleObject, include: undefined };
            }),
          };
        }),
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

https://gist.github.com/PhilippMolitor/00f427d12a9c5bca84309058d88846b7

Comment: I'll definitely need to give this a try when I can, nice work

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to automatically remove the include path setting mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65910081/130060) using [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired).

The following `config-overrides.js` works for `react-scripts:4.0.3` and causes babel to also transpile files in node-modules.

```
// config-overrides.js
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  // This line might break with other react-script versions
  delete config.module.rules[1].oneOf[2].include
  return config
}
```

Comment: Eek that looks a little suspect... but I suppose there are not many alternatives.

Comment: It is, indeed, tremendously suspect. But probably better than the alternatives...

Answer (score 2):

The other answers to this question suggest removing the `include` in `react-scripts`' `webpack.config` (either with `craco` or `react-app-rewired`). I found this worked with `yarn start`, but when I made a production build with `yarn build` I got the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined` at runtime.

Instead of removing the include, I had to add the other project's src in addition to the existing src directory.
Here's my `config-overrides.js` to be used with `react-app-rewired`.

For `react-scripts` 4:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = function override(config) {
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893787/create-react-app-with-typescript-and-npm-link-enums-causing-module-parse-failed.
    config.module.rules[1].oneOf[2].include = [
        path.join(__dirname, './src'),
        path.join(__dirname, '../backend/src')
    ];
    return config
}
```

For `react-scripts` 5:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = function override(config) {
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893787/create-react-app-with-typescript-and-npm-link-enums-causing-module-parse-failed.
    config.module.rules[1].oneOf[3].include = [
        path.join(__dirname, './src'),
        path.join(__dirname, '../backend/src')
    ];
    return config
}
```

Comment: What's `../backend/src`?

Comment: `../backend` is the other project I want to include code from, `../shared` in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

My craco config, does the same thing as Phil Mo's version as far as I can tell but is easier to understand

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        configure: (webpackConfig) => {
            webpackConfig.module.rules[0].oneOf.find(
                ({ test: t }) =>
                    t != null &&
                    !Array.isArray(t) &&
                    t.toString().includes('ts')
            ).include = undefined

            return webpackConfig
        }
    }
}
```